# Creating lambdas iteractively in Python: why does this approach work but the other one doesn't?

Tags: python, lambda

I've been trying to create a bunch of lambdas, one for each key in a dictionary, without having to do them one by one. I ended up achieving what I wanted to, but I want to understand why my first approach didn't work, while the second one did. I assumed they would produce the exact same results... I don't see what I'm missing!

I've included a small reprex below:

```
# approach 1 ========================================
bunch_of_funcs = {
    "func1": None,
    "func2": None,
    "func3": None,
    "func4": None,
}

for func_name in bunch_of_funcs:
    bunch_of_funcs[func_name] = lambda: print(func_name)

# now executing... prints func4 4 times
for func in bunch_of_funcs.values():
    func()

# approach 2 ========================================
def lambda_func(func_name):
    return lambda: print(func_name)

for func_name in bunch_of_funcs:
    bunch_of_funcs[func_name] = lambda_func(func_name)

# now executing... prints what i expect
for func in bunch_of_funcs.values():
    func()
```

EDIT: After chepner's answer, I tried "localizing" the variable by wrapping the for loop inside of a function. I'm still getting the same result, though... Where is this global variable being created? And why is it being changed on every iteration?
My change below:

```
def make_lambdas(dict_of_funcs):
    for func_name in dict_of_funcs:
        dict_of_funcs[func_name] = lambda: print(func_name)

make_lambdas(bunch_of_funcs)
```

Comment: Your "localized" variable is still in the scope that the lambda functions are declared in, so they still refer to the same variable declared in the `make_lambdas` function. It's not about local / global variables it's about the scope of the variable.

Comment: To ensure the lambda function is bound to the current value for func_name, the usual fix is to have a default argument which creates a closure over the current value i.e. `bunch_of_funcs[func_name] = lambda f=func_name: print(f)`.  Now the execution loop works as desired.

Comment: Thanks so much, Darryl! I finally get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, your lambda-defined function wraps a name `func_name`. However, that name refers to two different variables. In the first case, it refers to a single global variable. In the second case, it refers to 4 *different* local variables, a new one for each call to `lambda_func`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I still don't understand at what point I managed to create a global variable that's being changed at every iteraction, though :( I edited my question to add another attempt of mine that still produces the result that's bugging me

Comment: The index of the for loop is a global variable. It's the name itself that's captured by the `function` object created by the lambda expression, not the current *value* of that variable. When you *call* the function, an ordinary name lookup is performed on `func_name`.

Comment: Thank you!! I get it now.